# PHP code not recognized in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf-protection

I have a function that is being called when I click a button. The data I pass on the function is not enclosed in a form tag so I have to manually include the csrf token:

```
function NewDeleteBox(box_id, batch_id, staff_id){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'oss/admin/delete_box',
      type: "POST",
      data: {'batch_id': batch_id, 'staff_id': staff_id, 'box_id': box_id, '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>'},
      success: function(data) {
    
      }
    });
}
```

However, my csrf_token_name and hash is not working. It shows just like how I declare them in my data.

[image]

Any idea why I'm getting this? Thanks!

Comment: is this code on a .php file ? jst want to make sure

Comment: Yes. Because you are wrapping your PHP in quotes (thus turning them into strings )- so jQuery is going to treat it as a string - and so will your client.
Also, your file needs to be .php

Comment: @RiazLaskar this is on a JS file. This is in codeigniter so the url is the subfolder/controller/method

Comment: No.....only .php can handle that

Comment: You cannot put it in a JS file. .php extension tells your server to look for php in the file. It wont run PHP when the file extension is .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have put in all the code in a php file and still its not working then you can take another approach.

Put two hidden fields on the same page, assigned them unique id(s).
and then in this ajax function, get their values using jQuery.

```
<input type="hidden" id="csrf" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hash" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
```

then your javascript function should be something like:

```
function NewDeleteBox(box_id, batch_id, staff_id){
var csrf = $("#csrf").val();
var hash = $("#hash").val();
var postdata = {'batch_id': batch_id, 'staff_id': staff_id, 'box_id': box_id};
postdata[csrf] = hash;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'oss/admin/delete_box',
      type: "POST",
      data: postdata ,
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
}
```

Comment: yep I just did this. But the the hash is okay but the token name is not being picked up. I also tried directly adding those 2 when I call the function.but still the same. `csrf: hash` produces `csrf: some_random_hash`

When I alert the csrf, it shows my token name. But when I add it on my data, it's just `csrf`.

Comment: Did you check these two hidden input values using developer tool (inspect element) of browser ?

Comment: Yes. They have the right value. I'm confused as to why the token name is not being picked up. I also used `alert(csrf);` - it has the right value. But when I check the form data, the token name is literally `csrf` and not the actual name.

Comment: You should remove `'` from the values.
data: {batch_id: batch_id, staff_id: staff_id, box_id: box_id, csrf: hash},

Answer (score 1):

php code wont work on a .js file. just put it in a .php file inside script tags it should work fine.

```
<script>
function NewDeleteBox(box_id, batch_id, staff_id){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'oss/admin/delete_box',
      type: "POST",
      data: {'batch_id': batch_id, 'staff_id': staff_id, 'box_id': box_id, '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>'},
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: And the php script cannot be wrapped in quotes - else it will be treated as a string.

Comment: @Korgrue you are incorrect !!!, php code works in quotes too , u cn test it yourself, infact in situations if u dont put quotes u will get a js error.

Comment: @RiazLaskar All my js functions are in an external file so I want to stick with that. Thanks for pointing out my error. :)

Comment: then pass them as arg to the function it should work fine.

Comment: I tried that but I encountered the same issue with @Himanshu Upadhyay's approach. The token name is not being picked up.

Comment: like ws there any error ?? did u inspect element ??

Comment: Yes I did. All are good but when I examine the post data, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmWmT.png - the variable I used became the token name and not the value I assigned to it.

Comment: i may hv a solution to the issue.